# Json4s: Trouble while trying to convert Json attribute to java.sql.Date

Tags: scala, json4s

I am using `Json4s` to deserialize json messages. I have a case class like

```
case class A(id: Int, b: Option[java.sql.Date])
```

Whenever I try to convert a json message to case class A, I get none as the value of b

```
scala> read[A]("""{"id":1,"b":12345}""")
res2: A = A(1,None)

scala> read[A]("""{"id":1,"b":"12345"}""")
res3: A = A(1,None)

scala> read[A]("""{"id":1,"b":"12/12/2014"}""")
res4: A = A(1,None)
```

How can I fix this issue

Comment: Are not dates serialized as `Long`s?

Comment: (`java.sql.Date` might not be supported though see: https://github.com/json4s/json4s/blob/master/ext/src/main/scala/org/json4s/ext/JodaTimeSerializers.scala)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Any idea how to write a custom serializer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along these lines (you might want to be more specific with formats). And then mix this trait in the classes which need to have access to this custom serializer.

```
import org.json4s.DefaultJsonFormats._

trait JsonFormats {

  case object DateSerializer extends CustomSerializer[java.sql.Date](format => (
    {
      case JString(s) => Date.valueOf(s)
      case JNull => null
    },
    {
      case d: Date => JString(d.toString())
    }
    )
  )

  implicit val json4sFormats =  native.Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints) + DateSerializer    
}
```